# Redux action taking too long add one item to empty array - No Promise returned

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am using Redux to manage the state of my react app. I am creating an object, then passing this object to addTile function which is my action.

So my action.ts looks like this:

```
export function addTile(tile){
    return {
        type: "ADD_TILE", 
        payload: tile
    }
}
```

My reducer.ts looks like this:

```
const reducer = (state = {
    isPanelOpen: false,
    isDiscardAllChangesOpen: false,
    tiles: [],
    tempTiles: [],
}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "PANEL_VISIBILITY":
            state = {
                ...state,
                isPanelOpen: action.payload
            };
            break;

        case "ADD_TILE":
            state = {
                ...state,
                tiles: [...state.tiles, action.payload]
            }
            break;
    }
    return state;
    };

export default reducer;
```

However, if I try to use this in my component like this:

```
 this.props.addTile(tile)
 alert(this.props.tiles.length)
```

The length will be 0. However, the item is really added to the array, but at the time of the alert execution, the length was 0. From my reading on Redux docs, actions by default are async (or at least that's how I understand they are).

I even try to do this:

```
this.props.addTile(tile)
.then(response => { //some code})
```

Then I get cannot read property then of undefined.

Any ideas?

Comment: Actions no do not return promises by default, so then() will not work without additional code. You could use componentDidUpdate, but you may need to share more or what you are trying to really achieve after the item has been added to the array and the connected store has updated. There is middleware such as redux-thunk that can allow using and exposing promises.

Comment: Hi Alexander, yeah I read about redux-thunk, but as far as I know it's for async calls. However, I am just adding an object to an array of objects in my state. I am not facing the same behavior if I update a number of string property in the state. I am wondering if this is the normal behavior in Redux where it takes time to update arrays.

Comment: The updated array being mapped to props could be happening within a tiny fraction of time after you are attempting to alert the length. Middleware such as redux-thunk can be used with simple promises to allow use of then(), it&#39;s not just async fetch or similar. A life cycle method such as componentDidUpdate could tell you exactly when it&#39;s actually updated. If anything use something like performance.now() to see exactly how long it&#39;s taking, I doubt it would actually be a large amount of ms, but it's not going to be synchronous in the component.

Comment: So updating arrays isn't the same as updating other data types? I mean from Redux perspective, it's normal to take more time?

Comment: _'I am not facing the same behavior if I update a number of string property in the state.'_ you should use `setState()` (async) and then you should face the same behaviour - it's noticed in docs: 'don't read values just after updating state'

Answer (score 0):

When you try to check the prop right after dispatching an action, React has not yet had a chance to re-render.  It's not that it's "taking too long", it's that your own code is still executing.  So, React has not re-rendered your component, and the prop value is still the same.

Your promise example would only work if `addTile()` was a thunk that returned a promise.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I am confused on to why it happens only when I update arrays in the state. It doesn't happen when I update normal data types such as numbers or strings, I can alert the value after dispatching right away and see the changes, but not with arrays.

Comment: I find that unlikely, unless you're mutating the state in your reducer.  In either case, React has still not had a chance to re-render until later.